# Error funcion sento en protocolo UDP

Tags: c++, c, socket

Buenas os pongo un poco en situación a ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Estoy intentando comunicar dos ordenadores mediante un protocolo UDP. Un ordenador tiene un sistema operativo Windows y el otro es una Raspberry Pi con Raspbian. La Raspbeery Pi ejerce como cliente y el ordenador con Windows trabaja como servidor.

El problema lo tengo en el momento de ejecutar los programas. La comunicación en la dirección de la Raspberry Pi al ordenador funciona bien, pero al revés no. Me aparece un error con la función sendto de parte del servidor, y al hacer la función WSAGetLastError() me sale que tengo el error 10049 y no se como resolverlo.

Aquí os dejo los códigos por si alguien me puede ayudar.

Cliente

```
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "ReadWriteSock.h"
#include "changetypes.h"
#include "Socket.h"
int main(){
struct sockaddr_in Directionwrite;
//struct servent *Puerto;
//struct hostent *Host;
char pressure[5]="3.42";
char servo[5];
float fpressure, fservo;
int Descriptor,aux;


Directionwrite.sin_family = AF_INET;
Directionwrite.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("169.254.51.37");
Directionwrite.sin_port=htons(49205);

do{Descriptor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
}
while(Descriptor==-1);


do{
    aux=connect (Descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&Directionwrite, sizeof (Directionwrite));
}
    while(aux==-1);
    aux=sizeof(Directionwrite);
writeSocket(Descriptor,pressure,strlen(pressure);
int b=recvfrom(Descriptor, servo, 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &Directionwrite, &aux); //Tengo el error 10049
//readSocket(Descriptor,servo,4);
printf("Hemos recibido el valor: %s", servo);
close(Descriptor);
return 0;
}
```

Y ahora por aquí el código del servidor:

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET RecvSocket;
struct sockaddr_in RecvAddr;
int Puerto = 49204;
char RecvBuf[5];
char SendBuf[5]="Hola";
struct sockaddr_in SenderAddr;
int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(SenderAddr);
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(Puerto);
RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(RecvSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &RecvAddr, sizeof(RecvAddr));
recvfrom(RecvSocket,RecvBuf, 5, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr,&SenderAddrSize);
printf("Hemos recibido %s\n",RecvBuf);
// Ahora vamos a enviar un dato
int i=sendto(RecvSocket,SendBuf,strlen(SendBuf)+1,0,(SOCKADDR *) &RecvAddr,sizeof(RecvAddr));
if(i==-1){
    printf("The error is %d", WSAGetLastError());
}
closesocket(RecvSocket);
WSACleanup();
}
```

El error me da en este ultimo código al hacer la función sendto, recibe bien los datos del cliente. Y como dicho anteriormente, el error que me da el sendto tras usar la función WSAGetLastError() es 10049.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución al problema. Lo que hay que hacer es en el programa del cliente utilizar para los dos últimos campos la variable SenderAddr en vez de RecvAddr. Esto es porque al haber hecho antes un recvfrom, el campo SenderAddr se rellena con la información del cliente, y por lo tanto al hacer un sendto si incluimos esta variable en la función ya le estamos dando la información de adonde queremos enviar nuestros datos.